# "working" terminal prompt running in parallel Python 3.10

Tags: async-await, multiprocessing, progress-bar, python-3.10

I am trying to show an animated "working" prompt while running some python code. I've been searching for a way to do so but the solutions i've found are not quite what i want (if i recall correctly tqdm and alive-progress require a for loop with a defined number of iterations) and I'd like to find a way to code it myself.

The closest I've gotten to making it is using asyncio as follows:

```
async def main():

    dummy_task = asyncio.create_task(dummy_search())
    bar_task = asyncio.create_task(progress())
    test = await dummy_task
    bar_task.cancel()
```

where dummy task can be any async task and bar_task is:

```
FLUSH_LINE = "\033[K"


async def progress(mode=""):

    def integers():
        n = 0
        while True:
            yield n
            n += 1

    progress_indicator = ["-", "\\", "|", "/"]

    message = "working"
    message_len = len(message)
    message += "-" * message_len
    try:
        if not mode:
            for i in (n for n in integers()):
                await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
                message = message[1:] + message[0]
                print(f"{FLUSH_LINE}{progress_indicator[i % 4]} [{message[:message_len]}]", end="\r")
    finally:
        print(f"{FLUSH_LINE}")
```

The only problem with this approach is that asyncio does not actually run tasks in parallel, so if the dummy_task does not use await at any point, the bar_task will not run until the dummy task is complete, and it won't show the working prompt in the terminal.

How should I go about trying to run both tasks in parallel? Do I need to use multiprocessing? If so, would both tasks write to the same terminal by default?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use a library that already solves this, for example [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich)

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, thank you!

Comment: use a thread...